# Signification de l'expression « en général » et de l'adverbe « généralement »

Tags: sens, expressions

Cette expression et cet adverbe semblent signifier parfois « dans tous les cas » et parfois « dans la plupart des cas » ; existe-t-il un principe qui permette de prédire, au moins dans une certaine proportion des cas d'utilisation, de quel sens il s'agit ?

Comment: Un principe pour *prédire* ? Ha! Bah... oui forcément qu'il en existe! Des tonnes même!. *Un principe pour prédire* moi j'appelle ça un **a priori**. Ayant affirmé cela, je vous laisse tant, en la matière, c'est vous le spécialiste ici.

Comment: @aCOSwt Si on est d'accord avec jlliagre qu'il n'y a pas de différence de sens et que le sens est toujours le même (c'est à dire le sens « dans la plupart des cas ») alors tous ces principes sont d'une trivialité sans nom; vous ne partagez pas le point de vue de jlliagre?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C'est très simple :

Aujourd'hui<sup>2</sup>, « **en général** » et « **généralement** » signifient toujours<sup>1</sup>:

> dans la plupart des cas, le plus souvent, habituellement

et jamais :

> dans tous les cas, toujours...

On retrouve la même nuance de sens entre *global* qui signifie *de toutes parts, partout* et *globalement* qui signifie *en gros, majoritairement, plutôt* (ex. Bilan globalement positif)

<sup>1</sup><sub>Sauf bien sûr, dans une expression comme *il s'est déguisé en général* ;-)</sub>

<sup>2</sup> L'étymologie de général indique que cet adjectif signifie à l'origine "appartenant au même genre". Quelque chose de général s'applique donc à un groupe d'individus ou de choses. Bien que général puisse signifier universel, **général** peut souvent être mis en opposition avec **particulier**. Le sens [*qui est commun à un grand nombre de personnes*](http://micmap.org/dicfro/search/complement-godefroy/g%C3%A9n%C3%A9ral) est attesté dès le moyen âge.
Il existe cependant au moins une expression où *généralement* peut être compris comme *toujours* ou *pour tout le monde*. Il s'agit de **presque généralement**. Elle n'est cependant plus vraiment en usage dans le français actuel.

[image]

Comment: J'ai posé cette question parce que j'ai vérifié d'abord le TLFi, lequel à « généralement » donne  « D'une manière générale, dans la plupart des cas » et  en pensant que « généralement » a le même sens que « en général », en vérifiant « général » j'ai trouvé  « Qui se rapporte à la totalité des cas ou des individus ». Cela signifierait  que l'adverbe n'est pas équivalent à l'expression?

Comment: *Généralement* a le même sens que *en général*. *Général* a plusieurs sens en effet. Le sens *C.* du TLFi, *qui tend vers l'universalité*, est celui repris par *en général*, *généralement*, *d'une manière générale*, etc.

Comment: Il faut donc conclure que « généralement » n'est pas toujours équivalent à « en général »; alors la question ne se poserait que pour « généralement »…

Comment: ?? Je viens d'écrire que *généralement* a le même sens qu' *en général*.

Comment: Cela n'est pas très clair; en plus, un grand nombre de contextes que j'ai pu relever comportent des indices indépendants qui montrent que la possibilité « dans tous les cas sans exception » est la bonne; je ne me rappelle pas si c'est pour l'un ou pour l'autre mais c'est au moins pour l'une de ces deux formes. Merci des renseignements; je vais devoir attendre et chercher un peu plus.

Comment: +1 pour la note humoristique. Noter toutefois que pour un empiriste sincère... (il en est) *généralement*, tout au contraire, signifiera : **jamais**. Jamais... en particulier. *Généralement*, c'est *jamais* en particulier... :-)

Comment: @Montéedelait Je suis d'accord avec certains des argument liés à l'adjectif *général* mais la question posée porte uniquement sur **en général** et **généralement**. Il n'existe pas à ma connaissance d'exemple où l'un ou l'autre est employé pour signifier *toujours*. Généraliser, c'est faire d'un cas particulier un cas général, c'est à dire en élargir fortement la portée mais cette portée est souvent limitée. On n'amnistie pas **tous** les condamnés lors d'une amnistie générale. Le *bien général* pénalise certains, l'*intérêt général* restreint et s'oppose aux *intérêts particuliers*.

Comment: @Montéedelait Le deux premiers exemples ne me semblent pas très probants. Si généralement signifiait toujours,il n'y serait pas accolé. Je comprend *on s'est toujours généralement conformé* comme *on s'est de tout temps le plus souvent conformé*. Dans le deuxième, *si généralement* est plus vraisemblable comme signifiant *si souvent* que *si toujours*. En revanche, le troisième exemple est troublant et comme il n'est pas isolé, je vais devoir en tenir compte dans ma réponse. Merci !

Answer (score 4):

Il y a une nuance entre l'adjectif "général" et la locution adverbiale "en général".

"En général" a le même sens que "en règle générale" et "généralement" :

> Le plus souvent, dans la plupart des cas, d'une manière générale

Tu peux noter ici la référence à "d'une manière générale". Cela signifie que la situation a été **généralisée** : au lieu d'évoquer les cas individuels et de les traiter séparément, est choisi un cas majoritairement représenté afin de simplifier l'approche de la situation. Cette locution est souvent utilisée pour mettre en exergue les cas qui **ne se rapportent pas** au cas globalisé.

> En général, les français parlent de "pain au chocolat". Toutefois, une partie de la population préfère le terme "chocolatine".

L'adjectif "général" utilisé seul indique une majorité tellement prédominante que les cas particuliers sont de vraies anomalies qui n'ont pas d'intérêt à être évoqué.

> Cancer généralisé, opinion générale

Answer (score 3):

Pour répondre à la question de l'OP en commentaires dans l'OP.

***"en général"* s'oppose à *"en particulier"***
 et conséquemment *généralement* à *particulièrement*.

Si je cause du contributeur de FSE *en général*, je ne parle pas de tous les contributeurs, ni même de la majorité d'entre eux, je ne parle juste pas de *chacun en particulier*.

Dire *en général* c'est : généraliser! (J'espère bien un +1 rien que pour celle-là!)

C'est encore à dire faire abstraction d'un certain nombre de propriétés, de caractéristiques particulières, qui fondent l'individualité.

Comme on peut le voir, *en général* ne porte pour l'instant, **strictement aucun** sens de nombre, de quantité, de rapport, de proportion, de toujours, du plus souvent ou de quoi que ce soit du genre.

C'est là qu'intervient la **confiance** que l'interlocuteur porte au **modèle**, à la **réduction** du modèle, à l'auteur, au principe de l'abstraction.

Ainsi, si je vous dis que j'ai *généralement* raison, vous devriez, selon toute logique comprendre que j'ai *toujours* raison!
Et si jlliagre me dit la même chose, je comprendrai... qu'il a souvent pas tort.
Maintenant, si c'est Gauss... j'irai d'abord calculer l'écart-type... :-)

C'est cette **confiance** (j'insiste sur ce mot, car il est absolument fondamental dans le **contrat** établi avec le locuteur) qui va engendrer cette transitivité vers du quantitatif. 
Voilà ce *"principe pour prédire"* que vous cherchiez.

C'est un a priori bien sûr!

Pour s'amuser, et c'était l'objet de mon commentaire dans la réponse (généralement pertinente et particulièrement plaisante) de jlliagre (d'où mon vote) les empiristes considèrent que les idées générales n'existent pas.
Que ce carré-ci et ce-carré-là existent mais qu'un carré non!
En ce sens, dénuée de toute réalité, une abstraction ne représente rien. Rien... en particulier. D'où mon *généralement c'est jamais en particulier* <sup>1</sup>...

<sub>1  Si ça se trouve je l'ai peut-être bien piquée à quelqu'un celle-là... mais... je ne me souviens plus. Si l'un d'entre vous sait... merci de me le rappeler.</sub>